# Ruby on Rails, Promote to Admin function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to learn a bit, so I tried making a new function.

The error I'm getting right now is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/2"):
```

I'm trying to make a function to promote other users to admin, which is only possible as an admin.
My **users_controller.rb** contains:

```
  def promote
    if !User.find(params[:id]).admin?
      User.find(params[:id]).toggle!(:admin)
      flash[:success] = "User is promoted to admin."
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Admins can't demote other admins."
      redirect_to users_url
    end
  end
```

My **_user.html.erb** contains:

```
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    <% if !user.admin? %> 
      <br /> <%= link_to "Delete User", user, method: :delete,
                                data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
       | <%= link_to "Promote to Admin", user, method: :promote, 
                                data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And then we have my **routes.rb**, which contains:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'users/new'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

I can't exactly find what's going wrong. Some advice would be awesome!

Comment: Thanks for spotting that small mistake! But that doesn't solve the problem. It still says the exact same thing.

Comment: It is a partial page, yes, but the page itself is fine. The delete function works as intended. It's just the promote function that has problems.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either! Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: wht's the error u r getting.. and from which page u r calling `_user` partial

Comment: A page called **index.html.erb**:

`<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
    <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>`

Comment: put this in view `<%= link_to "Promote to Admin", promote_user_path(user), method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>`

Comment: undefined method `promote_user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f5506aa6060>:0x007f5504fcb088>

Comment: define in routes under `resources users` below this `get :following, :followers`,
`put :promote` or in routes only `match "/users/:id/promote" => "users#promote"`

Comment: Now it says this:  
  
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"

Comment: `resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers,                                                                         
      put :promote end end` - this doesn't work

Comment: syntax error, uexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keywoerd_do or '{' or '('

Comment: I updated in answer, see the answer

Comment: It says 'You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"' once again

Comment: check the answer again

Comment: Now it already says "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users"):" for the normal Users page

Comment: Try removing other specified routes for users..play with routes file

Answer (score 0):

`def promote
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.admin?
      @user.toggle!(:admin)
      flash[:success] = "User is promoted to admin."
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Admins can't demote other admins."
      redirect_to users_path
    end
end`

`<%= link_to @user.name, @user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(@user) %>
    <% if !@user.admin? %> 
      <br />
      <%= link_to "Delete User", @user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
       | <%= link_to "Promote to Admin", promote_users_path(user), method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>`

in route

`resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers,
      put :promote
    end
  end`

or

`match '/users', to: 'users#promote', via: :put`

Comment: Actually if I use this, instead of what I had, the complete users page breaks down.